# Oribasii Collectiones Medicae in Greek/English or Latin/English

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

I'm seeking a Greek-English or Latin-English translation of Oribasii Collectiones Medicae. I'm specifically looking for the section describing the setting of a dislocated limb where an interesting Greek verb (καταρτίζω) is used by Oribasius [AD 325–397]. I've found a Greek/Latin work but as yet I haven't found a Greek/English work. Is anyone aware of such a work?